# atribuir uma variavel a uma chave de vetor - PHP

Tags: php

Boa noite pessoal to com um problema que acredito ser bem simples mas não consegui resolver tenho o seguinte código:

```
function inserir($ccod) {
    $cod_cliente = $ccod;

    $this->template->set('title', 'Inserir Orçamento');
    /* Carrega a biblioteca do CodeIgniter responsável pela validação dos formulários */
    $this->load->library('form_validation');



    /* Define as tags onde a mensagem de erro será exibida na página */
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span>', '</span>');

    /* Define as regras para validação */

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('produto', 'Produto', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('orcdat', 'Data', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('situacao', 'Situação', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('valor', 'Valor', 'required');

    /* Executa a validação e caso houver erro chama a função index do controlador */
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {

        $this->template->load('layout', 'orcamentos_inserir.phtml',$ccod);
        /* Senão, caso sucesso: */
    } else {

        /* Recebe os dados do formulário (visão) */
        $data['cliente'] = $cod_cliente;
        $data['produto'] = ucwords($this->input->post('produto'));
        $data['orcdat'] = $this->input->post('orcdat');
        $data['situacao'] = $this->input->post('situacao');
        $data['valor'] = $this->input->post('valor');           

        /* Chama a função inserir do modelo */
        if ($this->model->inserir($data)) {
            redirect('clientes');
        } else {
            log_message('error', 'Erro ao inserir Orçamento.');
        }
    }
}
```

o que eu quero é que atribuir o valor que estou recebendo na função inserir no caso $CCOD, ao um campo $data['cliente'] para posteriormente salvar este código no banco de dados mas ao fazer como fiz acima eu recebo o seguinte erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente adicionar `$data = array();` antes de atribuir `$data['cliente'];`, pois parece que a variável `$data` não está definida neste ponto.

Comment: oi obrigada pela dica, mas continua com o mesmo erro.

Comment: Dê um `print_r($data); exit;` acima dessa linha: `$this->model->inserir($data)`, e veja se a variável contem o *$cod_cliente*

Comment: Você está recebendo o parâmetro $ccod nulo e consequentemente atribuindo nulo ao $cod_cliente. Que por sua vez atribui nulo ao $data['cliente'] que não pode ser nulo.

Comment: Ae que fica estranho, pois se eu der um echo logo abaixo de $cod_cliente = $ccod; ele me mostra o valor correto atribuido a $cod_cliente; mas se eu der um print_r($data); exit; acima dessa linha: $this->model->inserir($data) ele esta como nulo.